# Looping through all links that start with

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm making a script for web scraping and I need it to loop through all the links that have a known start, but random endings, and I have been searching but I can't find anything that helps me.

Everything else in the script works, I just have that problem with `ways`, which I want it to be anything. It could be `a-22`or `nb-5889a` or anything along those lines. I don't know what endings it could have, that's why I want the loop to loop through anything that has `http://www.trytrytrytry.com/"+y+"/"` as a start.

So the loop would be something like:

```
    place=['california','new-york','ohio']    
    ways=""
    objects=""
    for y in states:
        try:
           for z in ways:
               soup=make_soup("http://www.trytrytrytry.com/"+y+"/"+z+"/")
               pk=""
               for data in soup.findAll('figcaption'):
                   pk=pk+"\n"+data.text
               objects=objects+"\n"+"\n"+pk[1:]
        except:
            pass

    object=objects.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')`
```

Thank you  in advance.

Comment: Is it Python? Please specify language you're using in tags

Comment: if z.startswith("http://www.trytrytrytr...")

Comment: Can you reiterate your question with proper requirement. Sounds pretty unclear what your need is!?